# Exporting only one animation to gltf from multiple objects each with an action

Tags: animation, gltf

I want to do an animated gltf file that shows how a set of molecules move.  Using python, I created an object for each atom, 1558 atoms in total and then I added keyframes  for updating the locations each frame.  Then I exported to gltf and I can see the molecules moving alright in the [online viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/).  The problem is that there is an animation per each atom and I want only one animation in the file that includes all the atoms.
[image]

I tried putting all the actions in a single NLA strip but when I export the file I don't even see the strip in the viewer, not sure why (I do select the option for exporting NLA strips) and I still see the 1558 different animations.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
If I create a few spheres and add keyframes manually, then everything is exported to a single animation as I want.  When I compare this to the file generated with python, I see that the F curves created for the objects actions are grouped into an ActionGroup called 'object tranfroms' but that group is not generated when I insert the keyframes by scripting.  I don't know if that grouping makes the GLTF have a single animation as I want.
How can I insert a keyframe programmatically  that exactly replicates what happens when you manually press I over the object to insert it?  I already tried adding an ActionGroup to the object but it is a read-only type and I think you can't add a F Curve to it.

Comment: Did you try turning off the "Group by NLA Track" checkbox?  When that box is turned off, all movements in the Blender project should be lumped together into a single glTF animation.

Comment: I did with no luck.  After many hours trial and error, I found that you have to group all the channels and then export without grouping by NLA Track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but I got it to work by grouping the channels using this code:

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    new_group=obj.animation_data.action.groups.new("ChGroup")
    for fc in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        fc.group=new_group
```

And then exporting to gltf without selecting NLA Track:

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(export_format='GLB', filepath=filepath, export_nla_strips =False )
```

Now there is only one animation in the gltf (the color is different too but that's unrelated):

[image]

Comment: I was wrong about the channels having to be in a group.  What was working was exporting with the NLA strips option set to False.  I guess that when I was exporting from Blender I was changing the other predeterminate values as well.